# Set the value of an input field on change of a field

Tags: reactjs

In the application I have to take the value from `Input Value` field and set the value from `Input Value` field to `Set Value` field. When `Input Value` changes onChange function is trigger and value is assigned to variable. The variable `v` is being used in `Set Value` field to set the value of the input.

Value isn't being set on `Set Value` field.

I have prepared a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-payne-5jgury?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the issue I'm having.

```
export default function App() {
  let v = "0.00";

  function onChange(event) {
    v = event.target.value;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Input Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        step="0.01"
        placeholder="0.00"
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Set Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input value={v} type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" readOnly />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `useState` to update values on re-rendering

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0.00") //call useState to re-render UI as well as get new values

  function onChange(event) {
    setValue(event.target.value) //update your value here
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Input Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        step="0.01"
        placeholder="0.00"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Set Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input value={value} type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" readOnly />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: No need to write onChange = {(e) => onChange(e)} just pass the function reference so you could write onChange = {onChange} it would still work.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to track data in a React component that persists between renders, you need to use state (or a ref, or other patterns, but state works best for your situation).

The new React beta Docs have a fantastic section on managing state: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reacting-to-input-with-state

You'll want to do something like:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [v, setV] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Input Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input
        type="number"
        step="0.01"
        placeholder="0.00"
        onChange={(e) => setV(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Set Value</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input value={v} type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" readOnly />
    </div>
  );
}
```